# Multiple select boxes and Dynamically generated link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very basic select menu. Currently it uses switch function. Based on the selection I can assign link to the button. The block for me here is how can I have multiple select boxes and based on at least to selectors to grab the link and assign it to the button.

For example in first select box I will have : Cars, Bikes, Jeeps. Based on the selection for example "Cars" I would like a second select box to show relevant choices (BMW 3, Audi A4 and etc). On change of the vehicle to show the relevant one. For example "Bikes" to show "Honda, Apprilia" and etc. Is this feasible with [my current code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#basic_plan').change(function(e) {
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {

      case "ann":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.google.com");
        break;
      case "bi":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.yahoo.com");
        break;
      case "tri":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.bing.com");
        break;
        /* and so on*/
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-plans">
  <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
    <option value="tri">Cars</option>
    <option value="bi">Bikes</option>
    <option value="ann">Jeeps</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
  <a id="abc" href="something"> Visit now </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to make related combos. Please, see how to make related select combos in google. You'll obtain thousands of ways.

Comment: Actually what is you problem..??

Comment: Sharma SK I want to add second select menu. If I select only one item of the first to be able to go to relevant link or if I select item from the second select box to go to the link again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `class` to the new `select` elements to make them hidden by default (and when `change()` triggers), then altering its visibility depending on the choice you make on their `id`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#basic_plan').change(function() {
    $('.second-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "ann":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.google.com");
        $('#jeeps').show();
        break;
      case "bi":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.yahoo.com");
        $('#bikes').show();
        break;
      case "tri":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.bing.com");
        $('#cars').show();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });
});
```

For second `select` element:

```
$('.second-select').change(function() {
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.example.com");
        break;
      case "2":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.bitbucket.org");
        break;
      case "3":
        $('.button-plans a').attr('href', "www.facebook.com");
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

[**JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8p0d0rsa/5/)

**Note**: The reason you get a 404 from the anchor(s) is that JsFiddle adds a default URL and your link as URI.

Comment: Thanks urbz it looks great! The only thing that is not working: How do I assign different url for the second select option? I've tried adding case but it still select the parent link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#basic_plan').change(function() {
    $('.button-plans a').attr('href', $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-url'));
  });
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/6oemzgbo/

Its works.

Comment: Greg it seems that the links give back 404? Also how would it know when I add the second select box that it should be the dominant choice for the url?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/6oemzgbo/2/. You can delete target="_blank" if you want.